# Javascript object not showing all results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used a for loop to put all elements of an array in `vm.klassen`. I used console.log to see if all elements are put in that `vm.klassen`, which is the case.

I'm trying to show the results in the frontend, but it's only showing the last result.

For loop:

```
if (vm.tijdvak.klassen.length > 1) {
          for (i = 0; i < vm.tijdvak.klassen.length; i++) {
                 vm.klassen = vm.tijdvak.klassen[i].naam
                 console.log(vm.klassen)
          }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p ng-if="vm.klassen">Klassen: <pre ng-if="vm.klassen">Namen: {{ vm.klassen }}</pre></p>
```

What am I doing wrong and why is it only showing the last result while it's showing every result in the console.log?

Comment: `vm.tijdvak.klassen.length > 1` is only true if there's 2 or more ... you know that, right?

Comment: Yes. I have a check that I have not showed to check if there is only 1 element in the array. This check is for multiple.

Comment: You're overriding `vm.klassen` in every loop cycle. If you want `vm.klassen` to be an array of the name you can do something like this: `vm.klassen.push(vm.tijdvak.klassen[i].naam)`. Of course declare `vm.klassen` to be an array before the for-loop: `vm.klassen = []`

Comment: You're only showing vm.klassen, which gets assigned to every time the for loop iterates. This means the final value of vm.klassen incidentally is the last value of your array. You need to loop through the array using an angular directive if you want to see all of the values on the screen.

Comment: Makes sense. I thought they would still be put in `vm.klassen` because I only log it once and it showed all results.

Comment: And how do you want it to be printed?

Comment: @Lok-KwanFoo, you're logging it for every itteration of the loop. That's why you see them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing last one because you are assigning current index `naam`

```
vm.klassen = vm.tijdvak.klassen[i].naam
```

It'll replace the previous `naam`

All you need is **[ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)**

Like this

```
<div ng-repeat="klassen in vm.tijdvak.klassen">
 {{klassen.naam}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to use ng-repeat, but it was giving me some weird layout bugs, so I wanted to avoid it. But I didn't think of using just div lol!

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding `vm.klassen` in every loop cycle. If you want `vm.klassen` to be an array of the name you can do something like this: `vm.klassen.push(vm.tijdvak.klassen[i].naam)`. Of course declare `vm.klassen` to be an array before the for-loop: `vm.klassen = []`